# Spring Security OAuth2 SSO Microservice - Header not passed for /oauth/authorize

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I want to implement a microservice application which uses an external application for authorization. I have added the code in the [github](https://github.com/rohitnagesh/spring-cloud-oauth2-authorization-code.git).

I have the central application which is not part of the micro service application used for authentication and authorization. I create the token in my client using the oauth/token endpoint of the central application. Now I use this token for calling a resource end point of the microservice (http://localhost/user/userTypes) with the token(Bearer) in Authorization header. So it call the auth-service for token validation which internally calls the central for token authorization.

But during authorization (/oauth/authorize) call, the Authorization header is not available.

And if I call http://localhost:8082/uaa/user with the Bearer token Authorization header it works fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the token relay feature? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.SR2/single/spring-cloud.html#_client_token_relay_in_zuul_proxy

Comment: The token is getting propagated from the gateway to the auth-service, but in auth-service for /oauth/authorize call, the token is not getting propagated.